# What's the point in JavaScript window.onload?

Tags: javascript

I never quite understood this what's the point in using `window.onload` like this if the JavaScript load's anything not in a function as soon as the webpage loads?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  alert("hello");
};
```

Comment: It tells you when the page has loaded...

Comment: JavaScript from `<script>` blocks is run by the browser as soon as the `</script>` is seen. By putting code in a "load" handler, the execution is delayed until the browser has loaded all of the page artifacts (css, images, etc).

Comment: But you don't need to know when it's loaded by making a new function that's what comments are for.

Comment: So it's like JQuery `$(document).ready();`?

Comment: No it is not like document ready... That is a different event in the page life cycle.

Comment: Yes, it is like that. The "ready" event fires when the DOM is finished, but at that time the browser may still be waiting for images, CSS, fonts, etc. The "load" event happens when all that stuff is ready. (At least, it's *supposed* to happen then; there are many weird corner-cases.)

Comment: @epascarello well it's *like* "ready", but not *exactly like* "ready" :)

Comment: @DorkFace the assignment to `window.onload` could be written with jQuery as `$(window).load(function() { ... });`

Comment: @Pointy JQuery's document.ready fires when the DOMContentLoaded event fires, which is prior to the load event. DOMContentLoaded is triggered when the DOM is fully constructed, but load is triggered when the DOM is loaded AND all external content (images, external scripts, CSS files, etc.) have all been downloaded.

Comment: @ScottMarcus yes, that's exactly what it says in my comment (more or less).

Comment: Sorry @Pointy, the comment was actually directed at Dork Face's "So, it's like JQuery's document.ready.

Comment: @ScottMarcus ah OK, that makes sense. My comment was definitely the simplified version :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At
>   this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all
>   the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading.

So if you need to make sure that everything is loaded, than this is the event you need to wait for to fire. If you use the document ready or put the script at the bottom of the body, not all of the content may be fully loaded.

Why would you want to use it. Well back in the really old days, it was the only real way to know the page was loaded. But main reason is if you really need to rely on all the content being there for calculating heights/positions of elements, than you need to make sure they are all fully there and rendered. If you did it on ready, the heights may be different.

Simple test would be to load a large image in the browser. Read the height at the end of the body, document ready, and onload and see what the values are. (note once image is cached, the browser will have the right height)

```js
var img = document.getElementById("x");
console.log("inline:", x.height);

$(function(){ console.log("ready:", x.height); });

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    console.log("load:", x.height);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="x" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/74/Earth_poster_large.jpg?ddddddd" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful if you have a script in a separate file, or if you have separate files with other resources that you want to be loaded first.